# subgraph isomorphism: multiple subgraphs with disjoint sets of nodes

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, subgraph, isomorphism

All graphs are undirected and have no parallel edges/loops. All nodes have a "color" attribute.

Given two graphs `G_host` and `G_motif`, find a set of node sets (`{N1, N2, ...}` where `Ni` is a set of nodes) of `G_host` such that:

1. for every `Ni`, a subgraph of `G_host` can be constructed such that it is isomorphic to `G_motif` (the subgraph can be non-induced);
2. if `i!=j`, then `Ni` and `Nj` are disjoint (do not intersect);
3. the number of node sets is maximized.

Here is an example, let the motif be `blue-red`, and the host be

```
        1blue
        |
2blue - 3red - 4blue - 6red
        |
        5blue
```

What we want is `{{1,3}, {4,6}}`, or `{{3,5}, {4,6}}` or `{{2,3}, {4,6}}`. Just need to find one of the three.

For small `G_host` I can just find all subgraph monomorphisms then find mutually disjoint node sets, but it's getting too expensive even for `G_host` with a few hundred nodes. Is there a way to solve this without finding all subgraph monomorphic mappings?